# numpy.poly1d plotting many lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph some simple data and show the a polynomial regression line, seems like i'm doing everything right according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

```
poly=np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,20))
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x, poly(x))
```

However i'm getting more than just one line:
[image]

Comment: `x.shape == (397, )` and `y.shape == (397, )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `plot` method of Matplotlib connects the (x, poly(x)) dots that you provide, in the order that you provide them. Your array x appears to be unsorted, which makes the plot go left and right many times. Sort it before plotting, for example:

```
x = np.array([1,7,2,6,3,5,4])
y = np.array([1,3,2,4,3,5,4])
poly=np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 2))
plt.scatter(x,y)
sorted = np.sort(x)
plt.plot(sorted, poly(sorted))
plt.show()
```

[image: para]

Usually this doesn't come up because one plots the fitted model not against the points (which can make a rough plot shown above) but against some finer `linspace`, which makes a smoother plot. Then sorting is not an issue.

```
xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 500)
plt.plot(xx, poly(xx))
plt.show()
```

[image: smooth]

Comment: Thank you, now that you point it out I see what it's doing.

Comment: I expanded the answer, adding an alternative to sorting.